# my validation loss increases while accuracy increases. is it overfitting?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, training-data

I am new to deep learning. I am trying to build a bidirectional LSTM with a dataset of 500-600.

Here is my model summary:
[image]

After training on 32 Epochs and a batch size of 16. I get the following result:

[image]

Is the model overfitting? IF Yes how can I can change it? any suggestion on changing the model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the model is overfitting the training data .

To overcome this regularization can be done but you are already using dropout so try adding more examples to your training set.